# ERROR : "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. (W030)"

Tags: javascript

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 

firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL;


$("#btn-Login").click(function(){


   var email=$("email").val();
   var password=$("#password").val();

   var result=firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

   result.catch(function(error){
       var errorCode=error.code;
       var errorMessage=error.message;

       consol.log(errorCode);
       consol.log(errorMessage);
   });





});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqzSQ.png)

The "firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL;" Causing the error
how can i resolve the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is what you wanted to do, namely set the authentication state persistence to local:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
```

`firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL` itself is just a constant.